# how to access private array within member function in c++

Tags: arrays, function, private, member

Fruit.h

```
class Fruit 
{
    private:
        std::int no[3];
    public:
        void initialize();
        int print_type();
};
```

Fruit.cpp

```
#include "Fruit.h"
void Fruit::initialize() {
    int no[] = {1, 2, 3};
}
int Fruit::print_type() {
    return type[0];
}
```

Main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Fruit.h"
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    Fruit ff;
    ff.initialize();
    int output = ff.print_type();
    cout << output;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Assume the required directives are included inside all the files.
At this moment, I find a problem when getting back the ouput since it will not result in "0" but a garbage value. How can I fix it without using constructor?

Sincerely hope that someone would do me a favor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the way that doesn't use constructors and destructors, I hope you find it useful.

```
#include <iostream>


class Fruit 
{
        private : int* no;

        public : void initialize();
        public : void clean();
        public : int print_type();
};


void Fruit::initialize()
{
        no = new int[ 3 ];
        no[ 0 ] = 1;
        no[ 1 ] = 2;
        no[ 2 ] = 3;
}


int Fruit::print_type()
{
        return no[ 0 ];
}


void Fruit::clean()
{
        delete[] no;
}


int main()
{
        Fruit f;
        f.initialize();
        int o = f.print_type();
        std::cout << o;
            f.clean();
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answering.
Btw, why do we need to use int* type instead of int?

Comment: Because "no" attribute represent an array and not an integer value, so you have to make it pointer.

Comment: How about int no[3] done by me? Is it wrong to declare an array in class like this? Thank for your patient.

Comment: No, it's not wrong, you can do it, but I prefer pointers.. ;) If you declare it in your way, then you will not need more the "clean()" method and the "new" in "initialize()".

Comment: But the program runs fine when using pointer but does not work for int no[3]. That's still garbage value.

Comment: #include <iostream>


class Fruit 
{
        private : int no[ 3 ];

        public : void initialize();
        public : void clean();
        public : int print_type();
};


void Fruit::initialize()
{
        no[ 0 ] = 1;
        no[ 1 ] = 2;
        no[ 2 ] = 3;
}


int Fruit::print_type()
{
        return no[ 2 ];
}


int main()
{
        Fruit f;
        f.initialize();
        int o = f.print_type();
        std::cout << o;
        return 0;
}

Comment: Oh, I see. I instead want to ask whether typing like int no[3] = {1, 2, 3} is not correct?

Comment: No, not in C++. You can do it only on static methods.

Comment: Thank you so much! I finally find the bugs now.

Answer (score 0):

Please, read about constructor in C++. You don't know about the elementary things in OOP C++.

```
#include "Fruit.h"
void Fruit::initialize() {
    int no[] = {1, 2, 3};
}
```

This is not correctly. You most write `this.no` or `no`.

```
int Fruit::print_type() {
    return type[0];
}
```

What is variable `type`?

Comment: Sorry for typo, it should be "no[0]"

Comment: May you please to point out what is wrong for my program, sorry about that.

Comment: Better write constructor: <classname>(<type> name_of_parama,...){here init}

Comment: Umm... I am restricted to write without constructor at the very beginning.
Btw, thank you for your answering.